# How to pass variable get from javascript into xsl

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file like below, i want to filter out the target record by referencing to it's URL say *http://localhost/rc.xml?rid=2*, then the web browser will show all records with rcid=2

```
    <?xml version="1.0">

    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rc.xsl" ?>

    <RInfo "Location="KLN">
    <Info rcid="1" >1

    <RCHNo>1</RCHNo>

        <BrandNo>J252</BrandNo>

<Age>6</Age>

    </Info>
    <Info rcid="1" >1

<RCHNo>2</RCHNo>

<BrandNo>J132</BrandNo>

<Age>6</Age>

    </Info>
    <Info rcid="2" >2
<RCHNo>1</RCHNo>

<BrandNo>K152</BrandNo>

<Age>3</Age>

    </Info>
    <Info rcid="2" >2
<RCHNo>2</RCHNo>

<BrandNo>K152</BrandNo>

<Age>4</Age>

    </Info>
    </RInfo>
```

I have a xsl scrap below, what I want to do is getting the url parameter by javascript and massage it to retrieve the value after "="

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"

    xmlns:my-ext="ext1" 

    extension-element-prefixes="my-ext" 

    version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml"/>
      <xalan:component prefix="my-ext" elements="getrid">
<xalan:script lang="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    function getrid() {
      var ridstr= window.location.toString().split("=");
      //alert ("2");
      return ridstr[1];
      }
]]>
     </xalan:script>
 </xalan:component>
 ::::
 ::::
 <xsl:if test="@rcid=my-ext:getrid">
```

Comment: You should be able to do this: `<xsl:if test="@rcid=string($rid)">`

Comment: Hi Dimitre, it seems not function at all. I couldn't get the value of "3" in the string($rid). I just wonder if the document.write...statement in the javascript could really add the value to the xmldom object? I'm afraid I'm not on the right track.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you are trying to call a JS function from the XSLT transformation -- not all XSLT processors support this and if yes, they have specific, vendor-provided rules of how to do this. Search for examples ("xslt extension functions in Javascript") and you may be able to do this.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I've made the change as above but still no luck, there is no error report but the javascript seems not run actually.

Comment: What do you want actually to do?